# Weighted permutation bucketting

Tags: algorithms, permutations

Given a set of weighted permutations of numbers, an operation can be performed to combine multiple permutations that share numbers into a single rolled up permutation. What is the optimal algorithm to bucket the values into the minimal number of combined permutations?

**Examples**

```
permutation (weight)

1 2 4 (1)
1 2 5 (1) 
> 1 2 4|5 (1)


2 1 (1)
1 2 (1)
> 1|2 1|2 (1)


1 2 4 (4)
1 2 5 (1)
1 2 6 (1)
> 1 2 4 (3)
> 1 2 4|5|6 (1)
```

Comment: Without specifying the "operation", I don't see how this question can be answered.  Also, it's not clear what you mean by the number of combined permutations -- if you perform no operations, then there are 0 combined permutations (all of the permutations are uncombined). Where did you encounter this task?  Can you credit the original source?  What's the best algorithm you've found so far?

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer. By operation I mean that 2 (or more) ordered sets of numbers that only differ by 1 number and have the same weight can be combined into 1 set as in the first example. Furthermore one ordered set can be split into multiples with weights that add up to the original weight.

Comment: I don't have a best algorithm. It comes from the idea of wheeling tickets in betting.

Comment: Please don't put clarifications in the comments.  Instead, [edit] your question so it is self-contained and complete and reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  We don't want people to  have to read the comments to understand what is being asked.

Comment: An example is not a substitute for a general specification of the problem.  Don't force us to guess from the examples what you mean.  Also, I find the examples hard to read -- I don't know what that notation indicates, and with no words, it is very hard to make sense of the examples.  Finally, what do  you mean by a permutation?  Those examples aren't permutations.